# MongoDB Node.JS insertOne error: "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ObjectId | undefined"

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I try to insert one document into the collection, but I get this error when I specify the `_id` field of the inserted document. So how can I insert a document with `_id` of a type other than `ObjectId`?

The following code gives me that error. When I remove the `_id`, everything goes fine but the _id will be generated automatically. I just want it to be a string type. I know this is possible. I can make `_id` string using MongoDB shell.

```js
async function foo() {
  const users = client.db("test").collection("users")
  users.insertOne({
    _id: "a string",
    name: "Tom",
    age: 26,
  })
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to overwrite the default `_id` field if it's already auto incrementing ? If you need a string, can't you just add another field ?

Comment: If you want to use a custom string for _id you need to specify that in the schema https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id  otherwise it expects specifically a ObjectId or a string version of an object id (specific length). Did you do that in your schema?

Comment: `@Psidom` For some reason, I just want it to be string...

Comment: `@AlexanderStaroselsky` I've gone through this link you paste. It seems that this is not the official driver provided by MongoDB. I'm wondering if I can achieve this using official `mongodb` package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type your collection with `_id: string` it should work

```js
type usertype = {
  _id: string,
  name: string,
  age: number
}

async function foo() {
  await client.connect()
  const users = client.db("test").collection<usertype>("users")
  const result = await users.insertOne({
    _id: "custom string",
    name: "Tom",
    age: 26,
  })
  console.log(result)
}
```

that should give you the result you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers and comments. I finally figure out the solution.

```js
async function foo() {
  await client.connect()
  const users = client.db("test").collection("users")
  const result = await users.insertOne({
    _id: "custom string",
    name: "Tom",
    age: 26,
  } as any)
  console.log(result)
}
```

I'm new with TypeScript and MongoDB. I don't know if this is a bug when the `mongodb` package comes from common JS to TypeScript.